# How do you get the class of an underlying object in a Ruby enumerable?

Tags: ruby

```
a = [4, 5, 3]
e = a.each
e.class #=> Enumerator
e.first.class #=> Fixnum
```

How do you find out if e is an enumerator for an array, hash or other type?

Working in Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: You can call inspect on it, but that seems ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I propose that this is appropriate or in any way a good idea, but you CAN inspect an enumerator and potentially get some information that would give you a hint to the underlying object.  This of course, begs the question of why you would want to do this...

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
e = a.each
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
e.inspect
=> "<#Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:each>"

a = { :foo => "bar" }
=> {:foo=>"bar"}
e = a.each
=> #<Enumerator: ...>    
e.inspect
=> "#<Enumerator: {:foo=>\"bar\"}:each>"
```

You can then use a regexp to try to tease out information about the underlying object.  There are probably occasions for which this won't work (it does work for ranges).  I'd emphasize again that there's probably no good reason to do this.

Comment: Andrew beat me.  Usually I get a notification when someone has posted a new answer.  Absolutely agreed that this is a horrible ugly thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can't (easily).*

Nor should you be able to. Enumerators aren't meant to care about what's contained within them, they're meant to iterate over something. You probably shouldn't be passing around enumerators anyway: just pass around the actual object.

Though, you could do nasty things like parse `[].each.inspect` with regex for either `[]` or `{}`, or the case where it's another type like `#<Set: {}>`. But this is just so horrible. I suggest re-thinking *why* you want to do this—and then not doing it.

<sub>* Note that the non-easy programmatic way would be to write C code using the Ruby C API and tap into the actual object pointer within the enumerator. This needs to be done because Enumerator is written in C, and causes doing things like `[].each.instance_variables` to return `[]`.</sub>

Comment: B Seven, if you will ever decide to follow Andrew's instruction, here's a [place](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enumerator.c#L862) you might wanna start from. The `eobj` is the object you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would tentatively say that this can't be done.  There doesn't seem to be any requirement, when creating an Enumerator, to actually reference the source object itself, only to tell the Enumerator *how* to get to the next, current, etc... values